# Grails and HTML codification

Tags: html, grails, encoding, escaping

I know there are lots of questions with this item, but after visiting most of them, I can't figure out what is happening here.

I have two applications which receive a string from the same database and print it.

Database content:

```
<p>prob&aacute;ndo</p>

<p>probando</p>
```

Both apps have in Config.groovy:

```
grails.views.default.codec = "none"
```

Both applications recover the content in database the same way:

```
def list() {
    def results = System.list()
    [systemInstanceList: results]
}
```

To print it:

**App1:**

```
<div>${fieldValue(bean: systemInstanceList[0], field: "texto_gl").decodeHTML()}</div>
```

Result:

```
probándo

probando
```

Which is the expected result.

**App2, several tries:**

```
    <div> 
        <p><b>prob&aacute;ndo</b></p>
        ${systemInstanceList[0].texto_gl.decodeHTML()}
        <br>
        ${systemInstanceList[0].texto_gl}
        <br>
        ${fieldValue(bean: systemInstanceList[0], field: "texto_gl").decodeHTML()}
        <br>
        ${fieldValue(bean: systemInstanceList[0], field: "texto_gl")}
    </div>
```

Results:

```
probándo
<p>probándo</p> <p>probando</p>
<p>prob&aacute;ndo</p> <p>probando</p>
<p>prob&aacute;ndo</p> <p>probando</p>
<p>prob&aacute;ndo</p> <p>probando</p>
```

The first one is right, but it is just a test, the content doesn't come from the database.

What more can I try?

Perhaps it's worth noting that the first application is also the application which writes the content in database.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with:

```
${raw(systemInstanceList[0].texto_gl.decodeHTML())}
```

But I don't understand why both applications behave different.